# Android ADT Eclipse: com.android.common and com.android.ex imports could not be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, google-calendar-api, importerror

I'm trying to build Google's open-source Calendar app for Android (source here: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar), so that I may pick apart its code a little bit.  When I import the freshly-cloned project into eclipse, I get a bunch of `____ cannot be resolved to a type` errors.  Looking closely at the types that aren't resolved, the root cause seems to be:

```
The import com.android.common cannot be resolved
The import com.android.ex cannot be resolved
```

I've been googling and I can't seem to figure out what's going on?  I must be missing some library?  I have everything in the Android SDK Manager installed, even the optional libraries.  I've tried cleaning and fixing build path properties, etc.  The errors remain.

Anyone have any idea what I can do to get this thing to compile?

Comment: Probably some extra libraries or classes that are internal for Google if they're not in the standard Android package.

Comment: I wonder how I can track them down... it's all open source I think

Comment: i have opened an issue on github https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/issues/3

Comment: I am also stuck at this same problem, did anyone find any solution?

Comment: @M.ElSaka the github issue tracker for this project is ignored, I believe, since github is just a mirror for their google code repo.

Comment: Yes, you are right! ... I will give you my current working version. and sorry for being late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to add almost all the required dependencies and now i got an almost-running version.
Kindly, check it out from [here](https://github.com/mohelsaka/google-calendar-almost-running)

You can also check the last [commit](https://github.com/mohelsaka/google-calendar-almost-running/commit/bfd1ef8d334b243e9d5b5637fb5501eb7f720acf), it contains all what i did to get this running version.

Have a nice day :)